# Datepicker z-index как изменить всплывающее положение элемента

Tags: css, fancybox, datepicker

на тестовом сайте [ссылка](http://test.web-devsoltan.com/)  установил fancybox 3 и datepicker(air-datepicker) при всплывающем окне при установке даты datepicker залетает за форму как решить проблему

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделайте блоку `datepicker-container` `z-index` больше чем у `fancybox-container`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в css

```
.datepicker-container {
    z-index: 99999 !important;
}
```